# How can I cause the QuickFix window to close after I select an item in it?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I got the wonderful [bookmarks.vim](https://gist.github.com/AndrewRadev/1371174) plugin to my vim.  I especially like the named bookmarks and using the QuickFix window to list them.

In the code to show the bookmark list I'd like to add something that causes the QuickFix window to close after I select a choice.  How do I do that?

```
" Open all bookmarks in the quickfix window
command! CopenBookmarks call s:CopenBookmarks()
function! s:CopenBookmarks()
let choices = []

for [name, place] in items(g:BOOKMARKS)
let [filename, cursor] = place

call add(choices, {
\ 'text': name,
\ 'filename': filename,
\ 'lnum': cursor[1],
\ 'col': cursor[2]
\ })
endfor

call setqflist(choices)
copen
endfunction
```

Comment: Sounds as though it may be helpful: a means of toggling the quickfix window (close it if it’s open, open it if it’s not) is given at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_to_open_or_close_the_quickfix_window.

Comment: @ebenezer  I'll keep this one on the back burner for now.  I have `<A-down>` and `<A-up>` mapped for moving between upper and lower windows and `F3` maps to quit, so  `<A-down>F3` is just as few/many keystrokes as the given solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override the `<CR>` mapping that is used in the quickfix window to select an entry:

```
:autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>:cclose<CR>
```

<sup>Note: If you don't want this applied to location lists, you need to tweak the mapping a bit.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

in lua:

```
-- close quickfix menu after selecting choice
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
  "FileType", {
  pattern={"qf"},
  command=[[nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>:cclose<CR>]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above work, the `BufReadPost quickfix` event will also fire.

Here's the lua code for that ...

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
 "BufReadPost",
 { pattern = "quickfix", command = [[nnoremap <buffer> <CR <CR>:cclose<CR>]] }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for writing an answer. The question was about Vim, not Neovim. Lua code may be of limited value, here.